# Hide contextual filter parameter from view url

Tags: 8

I'm using Views to create a view which shows list of contents. The requirements of the view is something like this:

- The page display url must be `/mycontents`
- The contents must be filtered by current user(The content's author must be current user).

And what I did:

- Set `Page settings > Path` to `/mycontents`
- In `Advanced` > `Contextual Filters` , add `Authored by`
- In the contextual filter's `When the default value is not in the url` section, checked `Provide default value` and selected `User ID from logged in user`.

The problem is that after saving the view, the actual url of the view becomes `/mycontens/{uid}`. Is there any way to remove the `{uid}` from the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible if you show the view as a page, but you might be able to solve the problem by creating a custom route and rendering the view on that page, where you fetch the `uid` programatically.

You must do something like this in your Controller:

```
$user_id = 1;
$args = [$user_id];
$view = Drupal\views\Views::getView('my_view_id');
if (is_object($view)) {
  $view->setArguments($args);
  $view->setDisplay('page');
  $view->preExecute();
  $view->execute();
  return $view->buildRenderable('page', $args);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I haven't used the solution, but it's quite informative.

Answer (score 0):

Jdrupal's answer totally makes sense, but as some custom modules in my site implements hook_query_alter, I used it again to keep it easy to understand for other developers. The code goes like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  if ($view->id() !== 'MY_VIEW') {
    return;
  }
  $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  $snipped = "node_field_data_node_field_revision.uid = $uid"; 
  $query->addWhereExpression(0, $snippet);
}
```

- I took `node_field_data_node_field_revision.uid` from SQL query shown in the view preview (which needs to be enabled in `/admin/structure/views/settings`).
- If you add a filter this way, the contextual filter needs to be deleted.